# Проблемы с scheduler interval в apache-airflow

Tags: python, python-3.x, apache

Не корректно работает scheduler interval в apache-airflow. Согласно документации, код написан правильно, но не исключено, что в нем ошибка. Подскажите в чем проблема? За 25.03,26.03,27.03 dag отрабатывает, а при наступлении текущей даты и времени - нет. Крон выражения пробовал - результат тот же. Есть разница во времени между локальной машиной и временем в интерфейсе airflow (по умолчанию UTC), пробовал время запуска ставить и которое в airflow, и которое на локале - все равно ничего не поменялось.
Airflow 1.9.0. executor = local

```
'''
emailname = Variable.get('test_mail')
l_start_date = datetime(2018, 3, 25, 6, 48) 
l_schedule_interval = '@daily'

WORKFLOW_DEFAULT_ARGS = {
    'owner': 'owner',
    'depends_on_past': True,
    'start_date': l_start_date,
    'email': emailname,
    'email_on_failure': False,
    'email_on_retry': False,
    'retries': 1,
    'retries_delay': timedelta(minutes=1),
}

# initialize the DAG
dag = DAG(
    dag_id='test_dag_mail',
    default_args=WORKFLOW_DEFAULT_ARGS,
    schedule_interval=l_schedule_interval,
    start_date=l_start_date,
 )
'''
```

Comment: можно начать с [FAQ
Why isn’t my task getting scheduled?](https://airflow.apache.org/faq.html)